# Check if returned value is positive or negative

Tags: javascript

I am calculation the values of multiple textboxes with javascript. The calculation returns a value:

```
var totalValue = numVal1 - numVal2 - numVal3 - numVal4
document.getElementById("x5gr").value = totalValue.toFixed(2);
```

I want to build a check into this. If the returned value is a positive value (like: 100) the script needs to return a `1` into the textbox `check`. If the returned value is a negative value (like: -5)  the script needs to return a `2` into the textbox `check`.

Does someone know how I can build this check?

Here is my full script:

```html
1: <input type="text" name="x5cr" id="x5cr" onChange="getTot()"><br />
2: <input type="text" name="x5dr" id="x5dr" onChange="getTot()"><br />
3: <input type="text" name="x5er" id="x5er" onChange="getTot()"><br />
4: <input type="text" name="x5fr" id="x5fr" onChange="getTot()"><br />
<br />
Total: <input type="text" name="x5gr" id="x5gr"><br /><br /><br />
Check: <input type="text" name="check" id="check">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function getTot() {
   var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementById("x5cr").value);
  var numVal2 = Number(document.getElementById("x5dr").value);
  var numVal3 = Number(document.getElementById("x5er").value);
  var numVal4 = Number(document.getElementById("x5fr").value);
    
  var totalValue = numVal1 - numVal2 - numVal3 - numVal4
  document.getElementById("x5gr").value = totalValue.toFixed(2);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why is jQuery included when you aren't using it?

Comment: document.getElementById("check").value = (totalValue < 0) ? 2 : 1;

Comment: I think you need to revisit the basics. Stack Overflow is not a place to learn. It is for solving issues with what you already know. Your question shows a severe lack of research. My suggestion is read a book on JavaScript. Start from the basics.

Answer (score 0):

well, you could do this:

```
  if(totalValue > 0){
    // positive

    document.getElementById("check").value = 1;

  }else{
    // negative or zero

    document.getElementById("check").value = 2;

  }
```

Comment: This treats zero as negative. It's unclear from the OP how it should be treated.

Answer (score 0):

so you want to check `totalValue` is negative or positive? If this is the case you can just check the condition `totalValue > 0`. 
Try this

```
if (totalValue >= 0) {
    return 1;
} else if (num < 0) {
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: why do you have the `else if` clause, why not just `else`?  And `num` is not defined

Comment: ohh, yes. it should be just else,  if there is no more conditions. I was just copying from my program, bit lazy typing in..;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this snippet

```
 function getTot() {
  var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementById("x5cr").value);
    var numVal2 = Number(document.getElementById("x5dr").value);
    var numVal3 = Number(document.getElementById("x5er").value);
    var numVal4 = Number(document.getElementById("x5fr").value);

    var totalValue = numVal1 - numVal2 - numVal3 - numVal4
    document.getElementById("x5gr").value = totalValue.toFixed(2);
var output=1;
if(totalValue.toFixed(2)<0)output=2;
document.getElementById('check').value=output;

 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t7mgf9gy/

Comment: The OP is using subtraction so values are coerced to number anyway, explicit conversion to number does nothing useful (but might be seen as more maintainable).

Comment: Defining output as a global variable is not ideal

Comment: I fixed it @KScandrett

Comment: Great. But I didn't downvote you, only added the comment

Comment: @John please accept the answer if you are satisfied